# Question on convex polygons and their side lengths

Tags: geometry

Suppose one has a convex $n$-gon. What would be an example of an $n$-gon s.t. $3$ of its sides could not be the sides of a $\Delta$? If one has an $n$-gon that is around a circle, would it work in this case? How would one prove my second question? The help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Three lengths can form a triangle only if the two smaller lengths add up to greater than the  third length. Hence, to find a polygon such that no three sides can form a triangle is to find a polygon such that this does not happen. One example of such a quadrilateral is shown below:
[image]

Draw a line $AD$, then place the point $B$ close to the line (but far closer to $D$ than $A$). Then "nudge" the midpoint of the line slightly outward to produce another vertex $C$.

If $B$ is close enough to $D$, then $AB,BC$, and $CD$ cannot form a triangle, and neither can $AD,BC$, and $CD$. If angle $B$ is obtuse enough, then $AB,BC,AD$ and $AB,CD,AD$ do not form triangles either.

To create such a pentagon, nudge the midpoint of $CD$ slightly outwards to create another vertex $E$. To create a hexagon, nudge the midpoint of $ED$ slightly outwards to create another vertex $F$, and so on.

In the case of cyclic polygons, a quadrilateral is possible so long as opposite angles are complementary. I believe cyclic polygons with a greater number of sides are also possible, but haven't managed to generate a form of construction yet.